# Will a US visa become invalid if I travel to the UK?

Tags: visas, usa

I am an Indian citizen. I have a valid U.S. work visa.  However, my next project allocation is in the UK.  Will my U.S. visa become invalid if I travel to the UK (before travelling to the U.S.) ?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Why do you believe that US visa will become invalid if you travel to UK?

Comment: If your status is OK, and your visa/passport is not expired, there should be no problems!

Answer (score 4):

There are specific rules by which a [US Visa can be revoked](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/ilink/docView/22CFR/HTML/22CFR/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-500/0-0-0-1928.html).  If your trip to the UK will make you fit the criteria for revocation (e.g. you're going to shoot up US embassy or consulate) then the answer to your question is definitely yes.